# Regex for key value with value not starting with a char

Tags: regex, pcre

I am working on a regex to match key values pair in the format below. My problem is that I want to exclude the values starting with the character {.
I need to be very restrictive with the regex.

My regex:

> `^\s*(?<nodename>\w+)\s*(?<nodevalue>.*)$`

Example:

```
callingLineId {

    pid xxx,

    msisdn "xxx"

},

callingLineIdGSM 'xxxx'H,

portNumber xxxx,

mser {xxx},

xser {},

ppPser {xxx-pp},

cmReferenceNr xxx,
```

It cannot match the lines like:

`callingLineId {
  mser {xxx},`

It needs to match only the lines like:

`portNumber xxxx,
    msisdn "xxx"`

My project on regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/lvzyUj/1]

Comment: Can the curly bracket ever appear within a value?

Comment: Something akin to `^[^{].*` would be my guess. The first ^ means start of string, then [^{] - means any character except { followed by .* - any char zero or more characters.

Comment: @Lukos preferably not

Comment: The basic change is to replace .* (which is very greedy and generally a pain) with [^{^\s]* which looks for anything that is not a bracket or whitespace. The problem is that you have nested data on other lines so I think you will need to use various lookaheads to ensure you are not inside a nested group. This might not be a great use of a regex because it might start getting painful!

Comment: @Lukos i am processing the exemple line by line, not all together

Comment: But in the example above, the first "statement" covers multiple lines so how would you know if line 2 was a statement by itself or a child of a statement you are trying to ignore?

Comment: If you are sure that the whole line can not contain `{` or `}` you could try [`^[^{}]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Dsqdm0/1)

Comment: [You were pretty close. This appears to work just fine.](https://regex101.com/r/lvzyUj/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
^\s*(?<nodename>\w+)\s*(?<nodevalue>[^{}\s,]*),?\s*$
```

If the 'values' can have spaces, you may use this instead:

```
^\s*(?<nodename>\w+)\s*(?<nodevalue>[^{}\r\n,]*),?\s*$
```